# problem in login - checking input password with the hashed one in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my hash code for checking passwords, hashing.php

```
<?php
        //compare password with hashed one
        public static function check_password($hash,$password) {
            $full_salt=substr($hash,0,29);

            $new_hash=crypt($password,$full_salt);

            return ($hash==$new_hash);
        }
?>
```

This is login.php

```
<?php
   require("scripts/hashing.php");              
   $password=$_POST['txtPassword'];

   //checking in database if password exists or not
   $checkPassword=mysql_query("SELECT * from $tbl_name WHERE Password='".$password."'"); 

   $resultPassword=mysql_fetch_array($checkPassword);

   if(!hashing::check_password($resultPassword['Password'],$password)) {
    //back to login
   }
?>
```

The problem is that, even when users input wrong password, it is allowing the users to login.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    class hashing {

        //blowfish
        private static $algo='$2a';

        //cost parameter
        private static $cost='$10';

        public static function unique_salt() {          
            return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);
        }

        //generate a hash
        function myhash($password) {                            
            return crypt($password,self::$algo.self::$cost.'$'.self::unique_salt());
        }

        //compare password with hashed one
        public static function check_password($hash,$password) {
            $full_salt=substr($hash,0,29);

            $new_hash=crypt($password,$full_salt);

            return ($hash==$new_hash);
        }               
    }
?>
```

Comment: die you try to echo the result just before your return statement?
echo 'hash: "'.$hash.'"=="'.$new_hash.'"';

Comment: What would happen if a user would fill in a password that is not in the database? What would `$resultPassword` be? And for that value, what would your `check_password` do?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. First you get all rows from the database which password IS THE SAME as your given password (straight from the POST, not crypted). Then you check if they are equal? Well guess what - they are! Else the SELECT would not have worked.

Comment: omg! is my code wrong? I actually followed a tutorial. All I want is an input from txtPassword to check if it exists in database or not. In mysql, "Password" field contains hashed passwords.

Comment: So the `$_POST['txtPassword']` is supposed to be the hashed password? You expect users to type the hashed password? Are you sure you didn't miss a `crypt()` somewhere?

Comment: I kept crypt(). let me paste my full code.

Comment: But your SQL does `"SELECT * from $tbl_name WHERE Password='".$password."'"` - so if your table stores crypted passwords, your `$password` there is supposed to be cryped too. But it comes straight from a `$_POST`?

Comment: yes it does select from database. And yes again, $password comes from $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I used md5 to solve it.

In registration:

```
$pass_hash=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']));
$insertQuery="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Password) VALUES ('".$pass_hash."')";
$insert=mysql_query($insertQuery) or die ("Failed to register");
```

In login:

```
$pass_hash=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']));
$checkLogin=mysql_query("SELECT * from $tbl_name WHERE Username='".$username."'AND Password='".$pass_hash."'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($checkLogin)==1) {
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($checkLogin);
   echo "Login success!";
}
else {
   echo "Login failed!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling the raw password from $_POST and comparing it to a hashed password.

```
// Encrypted so that it can match in the database, otherwise it will never match up
$password = my_crypt_fnction($_POST['txtPassword']);

//checking in database if password exists or not
$checkPassword=mysql_query("SELECT * from $tbl_name WHERE Password='".$password."'");
```

Comment: Yes. I want it to compare the hashed one in the database

Comment: Probably because there are more logical errors in his code. Fixing this is step one.

Comment: I really don't know how to do it :( I followed this tutorial:- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/

Comment: @deepz: where are you hashing the password provided by the user? I do not see it. That is the point of my answer.